# Show that $|\{\varphi\in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})\mid \varphi=\varphi^{-1}\}|=4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, automorphism-group

I want to show that there are exactly $4$ elements of the group $(\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{15}),\circ)$ with an order such that it divides $2$, that is, an element $\varphi\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})$ such that  $\varphi=\text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}_{15}}\lor \varphi^{2}=\text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}_{15}}$ which is equivalent to $\varphi=\varphi^{-1}$.

Of course, $\text{id}_{\mathbb{Z}_{15}}$ is one such function, I've been trying to find another one (which must be of order  $2$) explicitly but I'm not making much progress. Even if I find the three other functions, I'm not sure how I'm going to prove there are on more  than $3$.

I make this post looking for some good hints on how to solve this problem.

**Problem**

Show that $$\left|\{\varphi\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})\mid \varphi=\varphi^{-1}\}\right|=4.$$

Comment: $Aut(\mathbb{Z_n})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_n}^*$. And it is easy to find the group $\mathbb{Z_{15}}^*$, and show that it has $4$ such elements.

Comment: @Mark could you please specify what you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^*$? I don't think I'm familiar with that notation.

Comment: Then I guess you are not familiar with Shaun answer's $U(n)$, either.

Comment: @RandomUser If $R$ is any ring with identity element then $R^*$ (or $R^{\times}$) is the set of all invertible elements, which is a group with respect to multiplication. I think I should have used the notation $\mathbb{Z_n^{\times}}$.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the clarification. The problem was just due to notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong U(n),$$

where $U(n)$ is the group of units modulo $n$.

Reference: Gallian's "*Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*, Theorem 6.5.

> By definition of $U(15)$, its elements, modulo $15$, are $\{1,2,4,7,-7,-4,-2,-1\}$; then the elements of order at most two are $1,4,-4,-1$.

Comment: I have the feeling that the set defining condition $\varphi^2=\operatorname{Id}$ has a role to get the claim without knowing that $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong U(n)$.

Comment: A similar approach (I was not familiar with the groups of units): For any cyclic group $G$ of order $m$, we have that $\text{Aut}(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_m^\times$. Use $G=\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ and $m=15$. As mark pointed out on the comments, it is easy to find the elements of order $1,2$ of  $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^\times$.